# How to make a self replicating program in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a little prank program where a form keeps opening until it hits a certain number like 50 or something, I've tried this:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

But that doesn't work, anyone willing to help? Thanks

Comment: `Show()` only changes the visibility of the current form. If you want to open a new one, you will first need to create a new one using `new`

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  `that doesn't work` is a feeble problem description and `anyone willing to help?` is not a good question

Answer (score 0):

Ditto what litelite said. If you want to show a **new** instance of the form, Show() won't cut it.

In fact, once you close that form, the timer you're using will be lost. So you'll need to handle the Form.Closing event as well. Since we're just having fun here, I'd suggest that you make that work like cutting off the head of a Hydra, two more replace it.

Try something like this:

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim _newForm as Form2 = new Form2()
        _newForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Me_Closing(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Form2.Closing
        Dim _newForm as Form2 = new Form2()
        _newForm.Show()
        Dim _newForm2 as Form2 = new Form2()
        _newForm2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```